# randomized search CV not applying the selected parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I hope you can help

I've been trying to tune my random forest model using the randomized search function in scikit learn.

As below, I have given the option of several max depths & several leaf samples.

```
# Create a based model
model = RandomForestClassifier()

# Instantiate the random search model
best = RandomizedSearchCV(model, {
'bootstrap': [True, False],
'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5]
}, cv=5, return_train_score=True, iid=True, n_iter = 4)

best.fit(train_features, train_labels.ravel())
print(best.best_score_)
print(best)
```

But when I run this, I get the below, where max depth and the min samples per leaf are set to values not in my array.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
RandomizedSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise',
          estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            **max_depth=None**, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            **min_samples_leaf=1**, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False),
          fit_params=None, iid=True, n_iter=4, n_jobs=1,
          param_distributions={'bootstrap': [True, False], 'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110], 'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5]},
          pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', random_state=None, refit=True,
          return_train_score=True, scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your chosen name for your `RandomizedSearchCV` object, `best`, is actually a misnomer: `best` will contain *all* the parameters, and not only the best ones, including the parameters of your RF model, some of which will be actually overridden during rhe randomized search. So, `print(best)`, as expected, gives exactly this result, i.e. *all* the parameter values, including the default ones of RF which will actually not be used here (they will be *overridden* by the values in `parameters`).

What you should ask instead is

```
print(best.best_params_)
```

for the best found parameters, and

```
print(best.best_estimator_)
```

for the whole RF model with the best parameters found.

Here is a reproducible example using the iris data (and the name `clf` instead of `best`):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

iris = datasets.load_iris()

parameters = {
'bootstrap': [True, False],
'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5]
}

model = RandomForestClassifier()
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(model, parameters, cv=5, return_train_score=True, iid=True, n_iter = 4)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Notice that, the default console output of this last `fit` command, even without any `print` request, will be:

```
RandomizedSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise-deprecating',
          estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators='warn', n_jobs=None,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False),
          fit_params=None, iid=True, n_iter=4, n_jobs=None,
          param_distributions={'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110], 'bootstrap': [True, False], 'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5]},
          pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', random_state=None, refit=True,
          return_train_score=True, scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

which is essentially the same with the one you report (and I have explained above): just the default values of your RF model (since you have not specified any parameters for `model`), plus the `parameters` grid. To get the specific parameter set selected you should use

```
clf.best_params_
# {'bootstrap': True, 'max_depth': 90, 'min_samples_leaf': 5}
```

and asking for `clf.best_estimator_` confirms indeed that we get an RF with these exact parameter values:

```
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=90, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=5, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=None,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```